# How to get JSON from the Blogger API filtered by category

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get list of recent posts from a blog filtered by category completely on the client-side using jQuery.  I'm really close and there have been a lot of posts here at stackoverflow which have been immensely helpful.  Here is what I have so far...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            BloggerImporter.getPosts();
        });

        var BloggerImporter = {
            getPosts: function () {
                var feedURL = "http://blog.mild.net/feeds/posts/default";
                var paras = {
                    alt: 'json-in-script'
                };

                $.ajax({
                    url: feedURL,
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: BloggerImporter.onGotPostData,
                    data: paras
                });
            },

            onGotPostData: function (data) {

                var feed = data.feed;
                var entries = feed.entry || [];

                var filteredEntries = $.grep(entries, function (value) {
                    return value.category == 'Mild.Net'
                });

                $("#blogTemplate").tmpl(filteredEntries).appendTo("#posts");

            }
        }

    </script>
```

Now, the problem is that each entry can have more than one category.  So, in that jQuery grep function above, "category" is an array of objects, where each object has a "term" property.  I need to filter by that "term" property, returning all the entries where that term property equals "Mild.Net".

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't simply run through all the categories?

```
var filteredEntries = $.grep(entries, function (value) {
    if( ! value.category ) {
        return false;
    }

    for(var i in value.category) {
      if(value.category[i].term == 'Mild.Net') {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
});
```

Or even simpler (I'm not sure about portability in this case):

```
var filteredEntries = $.grep(entries, function (value) {
    return !value.category ? false : value.category.some(function(category) {
        return category.term == 'Mild.Net';
    });
});
```